# How to use DataBindings in UserControls (works in page but not in uc)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

There are several questions about this but I understand too little about the subject to understand what I am missing.

It's my first time working in WPF and I want to create several submodules (what are called UserControls I believe) to make the XAML easier to read and keep everything as its own part and potentially reusable.

I followed a YouTube video online to get the following code working:

XAML

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <StackPanel>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Code Behind

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApp1
{    
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private ObservableCollection<string> _items;
        public ObservableCollection<string> Items
        {
            get { return _items; }
            set { _items = value; }
        }
        public MainWindow()
        {
            DataContext = this;
            _items = new ObservableCollection<string>();
            InitializeComponent();
            Items.Add("Item 1");
            Items.Add("Item 2");
        }
    }
}
```

Which correctly renders a `ListView` with the two items.

Now I basically just copied the logic. I created a new UserControl in a subfolder "Components":

XAML

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApp1.Components.ExampleComponent"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1.Components"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <Grid>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding OtherItems}" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace WpfApp1.Components
{    
    public partial class ExampleComponent : UserControl
    {
        private ObservableCollection<string> _otherItems;

        public ObservableCollection<string> OtherItems
        {
            get { return _otherItems; }
            set { _otherItems = value; }
        }

        public ExampleComponent()
        {
            _otherItems = new ObservableCollection<string>();
            InitializeComponent();

            OtherItems.Add("Other 1");
            OtherItems.Add("Other 2");
        }
    }
}
```

Then I added the following line into the main window's `StackPanel`:

```
<Components:ExampleComponent />
```

and

```
 xmlns:Components="clr-namespace:WpfApp1.Components"
```

as an additional `Window` property.

What I get now is the first `ListView` and a second **empty** one below it.

I'd like to understand why this doesn't work, and how I can fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to set the `DataContext` of the `UserControl`:

```
public ExampleComponent()
{
    _otherItems = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = this; //<--

    OtherItems.Add("Other 1");
    OtherItems.Add("Other 2");
}
```

Note that a `UserControl` should generally speaking inherit the `DataContext` from its parent element.

You can then bind directly to the `Items` collection of the parent window:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" />
```

Instead of setting the `DataContext` property of the `UserControl` and break the inheritance chain, you could bind to a specific property of the `UserControl` itself using a `RelativeSource`:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding OtherItems,
    RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" />
```

Comment: My mistake, I forgot to add it in this MWE. However, only adding the DataContext doesn't work. It's true that I can then bind it to the `Items` collection of the parent window, but wouldn't that be pointless (unless only for demonstration purposes). Finally, your last suggestion worked, so thank you :) If I misunderstood and your first code snippet should already work by itself, could you investigate why it doesn't? (+1)

Comment: Adding `DataContext = this;` to the `ExampleComponent` should work assuming you still have this in the XAML markup of `ExampleComponent.xaml`: `<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding OtherItems}" />`

Comment: For some reason it works now. I would swear I tried this and it didn't work, hence my confusion. In any case, I think I'll stick to the `RelativeSource` solution.

Comment: That's a good call.